# KeyDown isn't getting detected when keys are pressed

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class frmWhoIsFaster
    Dim player1clicks As Integer
    Dim player2clicks As Integer
    Dim startgame As Boolean = True
    Private Sub frmWhoIsFaster_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If startgame = True Then
            Select Case e.KeyCode
                Case Keys.A
                    player1clicks += 1
                    lblPlayer1Clicks.Text = "Player 1 clicks: 1" & player1clicks
                Case Keys.L
                    player2clicks += 1
                    lblPlayer2Clicks.Text = "Player 2 clicks: " & player2clicks
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The labels never change when you press A or L

Comment: The KeyDown Event is associated with the given control (main form, in this case) and thus the corresponding method is only called when the action (i.e., key pressed) is executed AND the given control is selected. If, for example, a textbox inside the form is selected, the KeyDown event of the form wouldn't be triggered.

Comment: Thank you sir, that helped me well. Things are now working.

Comment: Set KeyPreview() on the Form to True.